# Is that possible to remove <a> in a <img> in php or jquery without remove the <a> directly in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the `<a>` tag that is wrapped around the `<img>` tag. No link, only the image show up, no `<a>` html tag at all. But, without remove the `<a>`directly in php

I tried using css `a{display:none;}`, but that will remove everything. Do you think is that possible to do what I ask in PHP?

See the code below.

```html
<a href=""> <img src="" /> </a>
```

Comment: Note too clear on the question. Are you saying you want to remove the blue border around the image?

Comment: This is very unclear.  First you say you dont want to do it in PHP, then you want to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

[php](/questions/tagged/php) is a server side language. Unless you are planning to pass your entire HTML code to PHP, it most likely will not achieve what you are trying to do.

On the other hand, there are several ways which you can do it in [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). [One way to do it is to call `unwrap()` on the `img` element.](http://jsfiddle.net/vxc4b2tm/)

```
$("img").unwrap();
```

This will remove the parent `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jquery.unwrap`

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

     $("img").each(function(){
         var parent = $(this).parent();
         if(parent.is("a")){ //Remove only if the parent is "a" tag
            $(this).unwrap();
         }
     });
   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) into [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

contents() will return all the children of , including  nodes, and unwrap() can be applied to  nodes.

Use : `$("a").contents().unwrap();`